# How can I get the property grid to re-query for the PropertyDescriptor on a sub object whenever a given property of the sub object is edited?

Tags: .net, windows, propertygrid

I wish to hide most property when the “Enabled” property is set to false on my object.   I can do this with a custom TypeConverter (subclass of ExpandableObjectConverter) by overriding GetProperties().   However I need to tell the property somehow to re-query for the property descriptors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put [RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)] on the property you wishes value change to get the property grid to re-query.